# TextMate2: Disable soft wrap within Python COMMENTS

Tags: python, textmate

- TextMate version 2.0.23
- MacOS 12.4 (21F79)

The default behavior for Python COMMENTS in TextMate2 seems to be to "soft wrap" (and also indent):

[image]

I do not want this behavior. I want to disable soft wrap entirely -- EVEN IN COMMENTS.

I already have soft wrap disabled for Python in my .tm_properties:

```
softWrap = false

[ *.* ]
softWrap = false

[ *.py ]
softWrap = false

[ *.txt ]
softWrap = false

[ text ]
softWrap = false

[ source ]
softWrap = false
```

This successfully disables soft wrap within normal Python code. But the soft wrap within Python COMMENTS remains enabled.

I not only want to disable soft wrap in regular Python code, but I also want to disable soft wrap in Python COMMENTS.

How do I disable this default(?) "soft wrap in Python comments" behavior?

Comment: Have you seen the discussion in [How do I configure Textmate2 to turn off Soft Wrap by default for all files? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136906/how-do-i-configure-textmate2-to-turn-off-soft-wrap-by-default-for-all-files)?

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this does not provide a solution for my issue. Soft wrap within Python COMMENTS remains enabled even after editing my .tm_properties file as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a separate setting for `softWrap` (& in this case `indentedSoftWrap`) for all source code comments beginning with a `#`, separate from the Python settings (which seems confusing and unnecessary, but oh well).

To turn off (indented) soft wrap in Python comments, you must:

1. Main Menu > Bundles > Edit Bundles…
2. In the Bundles browser, select: Source > Settings > Style: Line Comments - Number-sign
3. On the right-hand side deselect the checkbox: "Enable this Item"
4. Close and re-open your file.

Now the Python comments should no longer be soft wrapped.